# why cant i see my option menu

Tags: android, optionmenu

I write an option menu code with a tutorial.

and for some reason it didnt work.

my checker_page_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:MyApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/waiters_filtering"
          android:title="@string/waiters"
        MyApp:showAsAction="always"
          />
    <item android:id="@+id/areas_filtering"
        android:title="@string/waiters"
        MyApp:showAsAction="always"

        />
    <item android:id="@+id/tables_filtering"
        android:title="@string/waiters"
        MyApp:showAsAction="always"

        />
    <item android:id="@+id/tapas_filtering"
        android:title="@string/waiters"
        MyApp:showAsAction="always"

        />

</menu>
```

and my totaly normal OnCreatOptinMenu in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.checker_page_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

What seems to be the problem and why cant i see my optionMenu?

Comment: you are missing `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`. Try adding it.

Comment: are you testing it on a real device? If yes which device are you using ?

Comment: Lal the super line didnt help , thanks 4 trying anyway
Blackbelt LG G3